# Not getting updated value from store

Tags: angular, store

I can't see what's going on here, so I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1seie?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fsearch.component.ts) to simplify and see if I could find it. I'm still learning about the store and am mostly following https://www.heavyweightsoftware.com/loading-app-wide-values-into-the-angular-store/ which is a tutorial I had working. There's clearly something I'm missing.

Here is my simple customer object:

```
export const CUSTOMER_1: Customer = {
  customerId: 1,
  name: 'James Bond'
}

export const CUSTOMER_2: Customer = {
  customerId: 2,
  name: 'Dirk Pitt'
}

export const CUSTOMER_LIST: Customer[] = [
  CUSTOMER_1, CUSTOMER_2
]

export class Customer{
  customerId: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Here is the parts of my store:

*app-customer.state.ts:*

```
import { Customer } from '../customer'

export const STORE_CUSTOMER = 'customer';

export interface AppCustomerState {
  readonly customer: Customer;
}
```

*customer.actions.ts*

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Customer } from '../customer'

export const LOAD_CUSTOMER         = '[customer] Load Customer';

export class LoadCustomer implements Action {
  readonly type = LOAD_CUSTOMER;

  constructor(public payload: Customer) {}
}

export type Actions = LoadCustomer;
```

*customer.reducers.ts*

```
import * as CustomerActions from './customer.actions';
import { Customer } from '../customer'

const initialCustomer: Customer = {
  customerId: 0,
  name: ''
};

export function customerReducer(state: Customer = initialCustomer, action: CustomerActions.Actions): Customer {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CustomerActions.LOAD_CUSTOMER:
      console.log('Storing customer', action.payload);
      state = action.payload;
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './components/search.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './components/view.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {customerReducer} from './store/customer.reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  FormsModule,
                  AppRoutingModule,
                  StoreModule.forRoot({
                    name: customerReducer
                  }) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
                  NavComponent,
                  SearchComponent,
                  ViewComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I have a search screen that stores values in the store:

```
  this.store.dispatch(new CustomerActions.LoadCustomer(customer));
```

When this gets stored, I get a console message:

```
Storing customer {customerId: 1, name: "James Bond"}
```

I had the above tutorial working and used it as a template. I don't understand what I'm missing.
and a viewer that reads that value on ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.select(STORE_CUSTOMER).subscribe(customer =>
            this.updateCustomer(customer));
  }

  updateCustomer(cust: Customer): void {
    this.customer = cust;
  }
```

But this shows as undefined.

Comment: ugh `state = action.payload` ?

Comment: @Stavm Is that a problem. Do you have another recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

`export const STORE_CUSTOMER = 'customer';`

when it should be

`export const STORE_CUSTOMER = 'name';`

to fit your app.module import:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
    name: customerReducer
}),
```

The more important issue, is with your reducer, you are altering the state.
state is immutable, and should not be changed.

so

```
export function customerReducer(state: Customer = initialCustomer, action: CustomerActions.Actions): Customer {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CustomerActions.LOAD_CUSTOMER:
      console.log('Storing customer', action.payload);
      state = action.payload;
      return state;
     // ...
  }
}
```

should actually be something like:

```
export function customerReducer(state: Customer = initialCustomer, action: CustomerActions.Actions): Customer {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CustomerActions.LOAD_CUSTOMER:
      console.log('Storing customer', action.payload);
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
     // ...
  }
}
```

or in your case, simply `return action.payload`;

p.s: apologies, I have just seen that code posted on the tutorial you linked to, I strongly suggest you find another tutorial to follow.